# When Enter Key is pressed in a textbox, redirect to page.aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

> This is the Code I've tried, on key up I want to be redirected to
>   another page in which the search result will be displayed using the
>   value entered in a textbox after pressing the Enter key.

You'll see a commented alert() I was testing and it actually works, it show the value I entered on the textbox after pressing Enter key.
But the problem is probably in the "window location"

```
$("#TextBox1").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //alert($(this).val());
    window.location = "RedacteurPage.aspx?val=" + $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem... What is not working??

Comment: The problem as I've mentioned before, I want to be redirected to another page when I press Enter on a TextBox, but it seems the redirecting method isn't working, I mean "window.location".

Comment: What does the Developer Console of the browser tell you? Any errors there? If no errors, in the Network tab of the developers tools do you see the redirect taking place?

Comment: Yeah actually there are errors in the Console.                                         
--- Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
 bootstrap.min.js:6:37
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 jquery.inview.min.js:1:1
-- Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: add your jQuery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js. I've tested your code on firefox and chrome. Works perfectly. It redirects when i press enter.

Comment: Actually the problem was in the  textbox tag <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox> I had to delete the "AutoPostBack" or set to false..Thank you for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
//works like http redirect
window.location.replace("RedacteurPage.aspx?val=" + $(this).val());
```

or try to use this

```
 //works like clicking on link
 window.location.href = "RedacteurPage.aspx?val=" + $(this).val();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I've already tried both solution, none is working. is there any other way to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be right and if the other answer doesn't work for you then you can try the `open` functionality

`window.open("RedacteurPage.aspx?val=" + $(this).val(),"_self")`

Comment: Thank you for answering, it still the same, even by using open it still stays in the same page, actually I can see the page loading once I press Enter Key, but it never take me to the page I'm requesting.

Comment: Then I think issue might be something else which you are not showing here.. Can you check what is happening in network tab of the developer window in your browser

Comment: Yeah actually there were 3 errors in the Developer's Network, but the problem was on the the TextBox tag, AutoPostBack was set to true.

Comment: yeah it's solved by removing the autopostback from the textbox control. thanks for helping though.